# Is there a way to iterate through a sublist and return a particular value?

Tags: nested-for-loop

I have the following dictionary, which contains nested dictionaries:

```py
rarebirds = {
    'Gold-crested Toucan': {
        'Height (m)': 1.1,
        'Weight (kg)': 35,
        'Color': 'Gold',
        'Endangered': True,
        'Aggressive': True},
    'Pearlescent Kingfisher': {
        'Height (m)': 0.25,
        'Weight (kg)' : 0.5,
        'Color': 'White',
        'Endangered': False,
        'Aggressive': False},
    'Four-metre Hummingbird': {
        'Height (m)': 0.6,
        'Weight (kg)': 0.5,
        'Color' : 'Blue',
        'Endangered' : True,
        'Aggressive' : False},
    'Giant Eagle': {
        'Height (m)' : 1.5,
        'Weight (kg)' : 52,
        'Color' : 'Black and White',
        'Endangered' : True,
        'Aggressive' : True},
    'Ancient Vulture': {
        'Height (m)' : 2.1,
        'Weight (kg)' : 70,
        'Color' : 'Brown',
        'Endangered' : False,
        'Aggressive': False}
}
```

If a bird in this list is truly aggressive, I am supposed to print out a statement saying "Cover your head." I can't figure out how to make Python iterate through each element of the list and print something only if the bird is aggressive. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, which iterates through the dictionary values:

```py
rarebirds = {...}
for bird_dict in rarebirds.values():
    if bird_dict["aggressive"]:
        print("Cover your head!")
```

Alternatively, you could iterate through the keys of the dictionary:

```py
rarebirds = {...}
for bird in rarebirds:
    if rarebirds[bird]["aggressive"]:
        print("Cover your head!")
```

Either way works; it is mostly up to your preference.